# How to create semi-transparent circular toolbar / actionbar items?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How would you make the items in the toolbar / actionbar with a semi-transparent circular background as seen in the latest Google Maps app (Screenshot)

[image]

would you add it to the item-icon itself (XML-Drawable preferred)? would you use the normal menu-xml to create it? I want to use it with a CollapsingToolbarLayout and hide the circular background when the toolbar is collapsed.

Thankful for any thoughts and tips on how to make this :)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: nope, i gave up on it. wasn't worth the effort for the project i was doing

Comment: also searching for this. the usual icon does not suffice because the button colors can become transparent if the image background itself has whitish colors at the top part.

Answer (score -1):

add imageView to CollapsingToolbarLayout and use `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`

example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
          <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:minHeight="100dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in code use `OnOffsetChangedListener` to listen to the state of appbar expand/collapse and you can change toolbar icon items

```
  final AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new   AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    private State state;

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            if (state != State.EXPANDED) {
                //change item rounded icon
            }
                state = State.EXPANDED;

        } else if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) >=   appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (state != State.COLLAPSED) {
                //change item default icon
            }
            state = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (state != State.IDLE) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Idle");
            }
            state = State.IDLE;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but what about the default backbutton and overflow menu?

Comment: well, i know how to use onOffsetChanged. Does that mean you would implement a custom overflow menu and backbutton?

Comment: you not need to create a custom, you can change the default icon of this items

Comment: how would i change the default overflow menu and backbutton? is there a way that's not too hacky?